# tinyMCE not working on firefox 5.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, tinymce

I've just realized that tinyMCE is not working when you use firefox 5.0
First I thought that's my fault with some script , but then I went straight to TinyMCE demo page http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php and there was the same result.

In normal way you open page, see editor, see text inside editor.

With firefox you see editor, but nothing is inside textarea. It is empy, blank. And what's more strange there is no mouse cursor inside of it. You cannot set it there, thus you cannot write there.

Later on I made one notice.
I've started to refresh the page fast, many times so the browser cannot work fast.
And I saw that it writes textarea, then converts it into tinyMCE editor with all text inside of textarera, and then on the final step it hides or removes all the data from textarea, leaving empty editor with all buttons visible.

Any idea what's going on?

Of course I've posted this on TinyMCE forum, and bugreported it also, but things there run very slow, and on StackOverflow I've got used to fast answers :)

So if anyone has any idea about how can I fix it please tell me.

**UPDATE**
I think something is wrong with my computer.
I've just tested cuteEditors demo and it acts the same way
http://cutesoft.net/example/general.aspx

So I think problem is inside my computer.

Is it Firefox or what?

**SOLVED** 
Plugins were the problem. I disabled all the plugins and everything works fine!

Comment: Works for me in Firefox 5 and 6.

Comment: I'm running 5.0 with Fedora 15 and TinyMCE runs fine.  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: We use tinyMCE (v3.3.9.3) extensively on a large system and it is working fine in Fx 5.

Comment: guys I'm not even using it. I mean I'm entering their site, with their last version. I cannot see their demo site

Comment: I suggest you start Firefox in safe mode and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED Plugins were the problem. I disabled all the plugins and everything works fine!